# save opus packet to ogg container

Tags: ogg, opus

I have opus packets which is merged from 2 frames.
Size of packet can be great than 255 byte (max segment size in ogg page)
I can split this packet into two packets with single frame and save each in separated segment.

But... Can we simple split packet into parts\chunks 255 bytes + last part less then 255
ang put it in sequence segments into ogg page?

It doesn't work to me (maybe incorrect code). But I am interesting how to handle it properly? We really need to repack doubled packets to separated packet? or not?

Sorry for my pure english.

Answer (score 0):

No need to repacketize. I forgot about special case when length of packet is 255, we need add 0 to segment table